# Show data only to selected user in Quiz activity

Tags: php, mysql, moodle

I am using `Moodle 2.7` and in the `Quiz activity` there is the overview page for **all attempts** of the **learners**. 
The table is under `mymoodle/mod/quiz/report.php?id=50&mode=overview`

Right now only **admin users** or users with the **capability** `'mod/quiz:viewreports'` can see the table. 
How to add users, **without using** any capability, who will be able to see this report?

Right now every user, without the capability gets the error from `report.php`:

```
$reportlist = quiz_report_list($context);
if (empty($reportlist) !totara_is_manager($userid)) {
    print_error('erroraccessingreport', 'quiz');
}

// Validate the requested report name.
if ($mode == '') {
    // Default to first accessible report and redirect.
    $url->param('mode', reset($reportlist));
    redirect($url);
} else if (!in_array($mode, $reportlist)) {
    print_error('erroraccessingreport', 'quiz');
}
if (!is_readable("report/$mode/report.php")) {
    print_error('reportnotfound', 'quiz', '', $mode);
}
```

The **table** **function** is under `reportlib.php`:

```
function quiz_report_list($context) {
    global $DB;
    static $reportlist = null;
    if (!is_null($reportlist)) {
        return $reportlist;
    }

    $reports = $DB->get_records('quiz_reports', null, 'displayorder DESC', 'name, capability');
    $reportdirs = core_component::get_plugin_list('quiz');
    // Order the reports tab in descending order of displayorder.
    $reportcaps = array();
    foreach ($reports as $key => $report) {
        if (array_key_exists($report->name, $reportdirs)) {
            $reportcaps[$report->name] = $report->capability;
        }
    }

    // Add any other reports, which are on disc but not in the DB, on the end.
    foreach ($reportdirs as $reportname => $notused) {
        if (!isset($reportcaps[$reportname])) {
            $reportcaps[$reportname] = null;
        }
    }
    $reportlist = array();
    foreach ($reportcaps as $name => $capability) {
        if (empty($capability)) {
            $capability = 'mod/quiz:viewreports';
        }
        if (has_capability($capability, $context)) {
            $reportlist[] = $name;
        }
    }
    return $reportlist;
}
```

I want to add designated people by their **id**, who will act as **managers**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to completely bypass the capabilities' mechanism for viewing reports, then you could always comment the array values in access.php corresponding to the key  'mod/quiz:viewreports'. In other words, you can go to /mod/quiz/db/access.php and substitute

```
// View the quiz reports.
'mod/quiz:viewreports' => array(
    'riskbitmask' => RISK_PERSONAL,
    'captype' => 'read',
    'contextlevel' => CONTEXT_MODULE,
    'archetypes' => array(
        'teacher' => CAP_ALLOW,
        'editingteacher' => CAP_ALLOW,
        'manager' => CAP_ALLOW
    )
),
```

with

```
// View the quiz reports.
'mod/quiz:viewreports' => array(
   // 'riskbitmask' => RISK_PERSONAL,
   // 'captype' => 'read',
   // 'contextlevel' => CONTEXT_MODULE,
   // 'archetypes' => array(
   //     'teacher' => CAP_ALLOW,
   //     'editingteacher' => CAP_ALLOW,
   //     'manager' => CAP_ALLOW
    )
),
```

or, alternatively, you can tune or turn on the entries according to your necessities. For more information see:
 https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Access_API

Then you can

1. check the ID of the current user ($USER->id) and
2. write some custom function to decide if this user can or cannot see the report.

Note: I would not bypass the capabilities mechanism, though, because it is reliable and safe. You could however tune it in order to allow only user groups defined by you.

Comment: Thank you Aldo for the suggestion. I would test and compare the results and give you feedback here.